# How to locate Intellji IDEA "Generate Test" related code?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Right click on a open Java file, we can get Generate item:

[image]

Then click Test and go on, we can generate target Unit Test:

[image]

I want to develop a new Intellji IDEA plugin base on upper build-in 'Test generator' feature, I want to check related IDEA source code, I just guss may be in some .jar in com.jetbrains.ideaIC library, and fail to locate it for a long time:

[image]

I have no better idea about how to locate the code.

Could you tell me where is the related source code, or how to better locate it?

Thanks for your idea!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the related package in the source code  https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/0e2aa4030ee763c9b0c828f0b5119f4cdcc66f35/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/testIntegration/createTest

Comment: Cool!Thank you so much. Could you tell me how you locate it? Just guss by experience? @quickfix

Comment: @wo4wangle well, basically you look at the name of the dialog window - "Create Test" - and then you look for CreateTest class in sources. Most time it will match or have something similar. Having sources checked out to your local machine helps a lot to navigate